Upload files doesn't work in Glassfish server 4.1
I'm using Oracle ADF 12.2.1.4.0 in my application to upload files to 'ATATCH_BLOB'. The application uploads files correctly when I run the app in the local ADF runtime environment. However, when I run the application on GlassFish 4.1 server, the file upload functionality doesn't work."
This is the Log file from Server:
[2024-06-10T09:19:39.396+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl] [tid: _ThreadID=68 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(3)] [timeMillis: 1718003979396] [levelValue: 1000] [[

  

java.io.EOFException

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler._skipBoundary(MultipartFormHandler.java:256)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:111)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.share.util.MultipartFormHandler.<init>(MultipartFormHandler.java:84)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.upload.FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(FileUploadConfiguratorImpl.java:148)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._startConfiguratorServiceRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:883)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._processPhysicalRequestBegin(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:529)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl._beginRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:508)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.config.GlobalConfiguratorImpl.beginRequest(GlobalConfiguratorImpl.java:220)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidadinternal.webapp.TrinidadFilterImpl.doFilter(TrinidadFilterImpl.java:193)

    at org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter.doFilter(TrinidadFilter.java:101)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

    at oracle.adf.library.webapp.LibraryFilter.doFilter(LibraryFilter.java:169)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)

    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)

    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)

    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)

    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)

    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)

    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

]]



[2024-06-10T09:19:39.603+0200] [glassfish 4.1] [SEVERE] [] [oracle.adfinternal.view.faces.webapp.rich.ServletWindowManager] [tid: _ThreadID=67 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1718003979603] [levelValue: 1000] [[

  _updateCurrentWindowIdForPartialRequest --> No registered window for:_afrDTSFrame]]

This is the code to upload file :
           
           // Add event code here... if1
           Row curRow = Utile.findIterator("Standred2024View1Iterator").getCurrentRow();
           //UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile)attchV.getValue();
           UploadedFile file = (UploadedFile)if1.getValue();
           
           if (file.getContentType() == null) {
               Utile.showErrorMessage("\u0647\u0630\u0627 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0641\u0642 \u063A\u064A\u0631 \u0635\u0627\u0644\u062D \u0644\u0644\u0631\u0641\u0639");
               if1=null;
               return ;
           }
           curRow.setAttribute("AttchType", file.getContentType());
           curRow.setAttribute("Attchname", file.getFilename());
           curRow.setAttribute("AtatchBlob", Utile.createBlobDomain(file));
           Utile.ShowSuccessMsg("\u062A\u0645 \u0631\u0641\u0639 \u0627\u0644\u0645\u0631\u0641\u0642 \u0628\u0646\u062C\u0627\u062D");
            // ADFUtils.commit();
           Utile.saveData();
       }


EOFException means that the server detected the end of the uploaded file but it expects more data to come. How big is the file? Do you upload it over the network? Is it possible that a firewall or something doesn't allow uploading bigger files and will cut the communication too soon?
